# how to create rain animation?

Tags: android

I want to create a rain animation. For that I am using a translate animation which moves the raindrop images from top to bottom. But I want this to be continuous meaning the animation should repeat itself.

I am using the handler concept and giving the delay accordingly, but still it is not giving the perfection that i am looking for and the app become very heavy because of the multiple thread execution.

Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some of your code

Answer (score 5):

You need a particle system for native Android. Instead of writing your own I would suggest using https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids

```
new ParticleSystem(RainActivity.this, 80, R.drawable.rain_drop, 10000)
    .setSpeedByComponentsRange(0f, 0f, 0.05f, 0.1f)
    .setAcceleration(0.00005f, 90)
    .emitWithGravity(findViewById(R.id.cloud), Gravity.BOTTOM, 8);
```

Credits to the author.

[image: simple rain animation]

Comment: actually, I added emitWithGravity for a rain-like effect in a release of the lib yesterday ;-)

Comment: not working. I am using for content view in oncreate

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
TranslateAnimation t1 = new TranslateAnimation(context, attrs);
t1.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**css**

```
html{height:100%;}
body {
background:#0D343A;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%,0% 100%, from(rgba(13,52,58,1) ), to(#000000)  );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13,52,58,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);

overflow:hidden;}


.drop {
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%,0% 100%, from(rgba(13,52,58,1) ), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.6))  );
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(13,52,58,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 100%);
    width:1px;
    height:89px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:200px;
    -webkit-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: fall .63s linear infinite;

}

/* animate the drops*/
@-webkit-keyframes fall {
    to {margin-top:900px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes fall {
    to {margin-top:900px;}
}
```

**javascript**

```
// number of drops created.
var nbDrop = 858; 

// function to generate a random number range.
function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}

// function to generate drops
function createRain() {

    for( i=1;i<nbDrop;i++) {
    var dropLeft = randRange(0,1600);
    var dropTop = randRange(-1000,1400);

    $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
    $('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
    }

}
// Make it rain
createRain();
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q87Th/1/)

Comment: That is a nice rain effect !